# dlib in python is giving accurate results then in c++ for object detection for the same model ( .svm file ) why?

Tags: python, c++, dlib

I am working on `License plate detector` and I came across `dlib` and I used it's wrapper in python to train a model and I stored trained model in `trainedModel.svm` file so that I can use it for testing, without training the model again.

And now I want to use This `trainedModel.svm` in `C++` (dlib library)
And The problem, I am facing is that of **Accuracy** , I mean in `python` the trained model is giving me better results then I `C++`, But Why ?? I don't understand this, because I am using same model for testing then Why different results?

Please anyone tell me the reason behind this accuracy difference and how can I increase It's accuracy in `C++` as it is `python`.